# Bucket Key Value Map?

Tags: c++, containers

I need a structure where I can push Key Values where the Keys are ordered ascending. If I request a Value to a Key, I would like to get the Value of the nearest bigger (but not equal) Key inside of the Map.

So for example, I do push 100, 500 and 1000. If I request 750 I do get the 1000 Value. If I request 450 I get the 500 Value. If I request 500, I get the 1000 value. Those keys are dynamic, a switch isn't possible here.

My approach would be to push a Class with a key and a value to a vector but this would last in a O(n).

Is there a better way/faster way to implement this instead of iterating forward through a Key vector and compare?

Comment: Have a look at `std::upper_bound`.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound

Comment: this is great! I didn't know of this thanks!

Comment: I think `lower_bound` matches what you are asking for slightly better, but other than that it is basically the same, present as a generic version and as a member of `std::map`.

Comment: @BoBTFish he want nearest **bigger** It should be the `upper_bound`

Comment: @Danh The question wasn't entirely clear to me, but I took it to mean that if both `500` and `550` were present, and he requested `500`, he wanted to get `500` (not `550). So I thought I should point out the alternative, then he can decide which one he actually meant.

Comment: @BoBTFish agree, we need the clarification from him.

Comment: If both 500 and 550 are present and i request 500 i'd return 550 since i am looking for buckets which can fit it which they cant if they are equal size.

Comment: Edited the question to include that.

Comment: Bear in mind that, while `std::map` is the simplest way to implement this, and should probably be your first try, it has poor cache characteristics. If you have strict performance requirements, you may be better keeping a sorted `std::vector` and using [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound). But profile first! And only if you have a problem with the `map`.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks for the information. I think that the amount of buckets are small and the buckets itself have a small amout of elements but you never know what people are going to define for the buckets..

Comment: do i see that right, that the pushback to it should be to lower_bound if i add things to the buckets?

Comment: @BennX Did you mean that you need some function to check before `push_back`? If your data are sorted before, you can just insert it to the end of vector. If your data haven't been sorted. I think the `std::map` is the simplest way to go. By the way, if you still want to use a vector, use `std::lower_bound` insert at the returned iterator (check for the duplicate first, of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use `std::map` as the container.
and use `std::map::upper_bound` to find the nearest bigger key.

In case of equal is acceptable, use `std::map::lower_bound`.

`std::map::upper_bound` and `std::map::lower_bound` is guaranteed the complexity as O(log(n)).

By the way, if you still want to use `std::vector`, `std::upper_bound` and `std::lower_bound` is guaranteed to have complexity as O(log(n)) for `std::vector`

Comment: `std::upper_bound` is a poor choice on a `std::map`; since it doesn't have random access iterators, the algorithms defaults to a linear search. That is why `std::map::upper_bound` is provided. So the guarantee you mention is only half correct. Other than that, excellent answer.

Comment: According to C++11 standard, section [upper.bound], **Complexity: At most log2(last − first) + O(1) comparisons.** I think my understand is correct

Comment: Yes, but you just claim "complexity as O(log(n))". That is the number of *comparisons*. But the iteration is slower, you failed to read the paragraph above, which says "They work on non-random access iterators minimizing the number of comparisons, which will be logarithmic for all types of iterators. They are especially appropriate for random access iterators, because these algorithms do a logarithmic number of steps through the data structure. For non-random access iterators they execute a linear number of steps." - Walking around through a node-based container such as `std::map` is slooooow.

Comment: Nice find, I focused on the detail section of the algorithm. I will edit my answer. By the way, I think the standard wording is too confused for me in this case.

Comment: Yes, reading The Standard can be, umm, "tricky". It is not intended as documentation for programmers. http://en.cppreference.com/w/ is pretty good as a quick reference, but you do sometimes need to check The Standard for details.

Comment: yes, cpp reference is pretty good for quick reference, but there are stuff which hasn't been changed for years, some stuff hasn't filled enough detail.

Comment: It's a wiki. Knock yourself out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::map` and `std::map::upper_bound()`. `std::map` is implemented as a tree, so `std::map::upper_bound()` is guaranteed to be O(log(n)).

`std::map` is sorted by the key using a given comparison function (default: `std::less`). It include should everything you need.

Comment: It is *guaranteed* to be `O(log(n))`.

Comment: @BoBTFish I did not look up the guarantees for `lower_bound()`. You are correct. I'll change my answer.

Comment: The asker has clarified that they do actually want `upper_bound`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use heap(min-heap or max-heap).
insert delete or find is O(log(n)), and easy to implement.
in fact it is similar to map, but you can code by you idea.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe how this would work, using the standard [heap operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Heap_operations)?